# String split method behavior

Tags: java, string, split

I don't see why does the following output makes sense.

String split method on an empty String returning an array of String with length 1

`String[] split = "".split(",");`
`System.out.println(split.length);`
Returns array of String with length 1

`String[] split = "Java".split(",");`
`System.out.println(split.length);`
Returns array of String with length 1

How to differentiate??

Comment: It didn't found place to split so it returned array with whole String.

Comment: I would say it should return 0

Comment: no this function always return at least 1

Comment: @lordlupine: If the search string cannot be found, `split.length` will be 1. If the string can be found, `split.length` will be at least 2. There is also no real difference between `""` and `"Java"` if you wish to split on `,` as neither contain the search string.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29):

> The array returned by this method contains each substring of this string that is terminated by another substring that matches the given expression or is terminated by the end of the string.

To answer your question, it does what it is expected to do: the returned substring is terminated by the end of the input string (as there was no `,` to be found). The documentation also states:

> If the expression does not match any part of the input then the resulting array has just one element, namely this string.

Note that this is a consequence of the first statement. It is not an additional circumstance that the Java developers added in case the search string could not be found.

Answer (score 2):

I hit this, too.  What it's returning is the string up to but not including the split character.  If you want to get no strings, use StringTokenizer:

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(someString,',');
int numberOfSubstrings = st.countTokens();
```

Comment: This code don´t work, single quotes are wrong and it will return 1 for a code like: new StringTokenizer("ABC",";").countTokens()

Answer (score 1):

It's returning the original string (which in this case is the empty string) since there was no , to split on.

Answer (score 0):

It returns one because you are measuring the size of the split array, which contains one element: an empty string.